# Only show the amount of views in Advanced Forum

Tags: 7, nodes

I am using the 'Advanced Forum' module in Drupal 7 and I want to have a 'Views' column in the topic list. I have managed to do this using the Statistics module, but now at the bottom of every node it says '## reads', much to my dislike. Therefore, I would like to remove every visible view count; only leaving the views column in the 'Advanced Forum'.

Is this possible? If it is possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove it through [`template_preprocess_node()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7).  For instance:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  unset($variables['content']['links']['statistics']);
}
```

Or you may be able to do this with simple CSS as well:

```
li.statistics_counter {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The CSS didn't seem to change anything but the function worked perfectly! Sorry for my delayed response.

Answer (score 2):

Also, the view count on nodes is permission based, so you can deny the view permission to everyone and then it will only show for UID 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I tried that, but I'm new to Drupal 7 so I didn't really know what I was doing. Anyway, I have a solution now, and me and my mate are 'pausing' the project until futher notice as well! Thanks again, and sorry for my slow reply!